# Tire not sitting properly after changing spokes

Tags: tire, rims, spokes

I've changed many a tire, but never seen this issue. It's not sat properly and is bumping against the fork (seems radially misaligned). Pretty sure the inner tube isn't pinched between tire and rim so unsure what the problem could be.

[image: image of the tire in question]

Comment: Have you tried to reseat the bead? Deflated the pushed valve stem up to make sure tube is properly inside tire?

Comment: The rubber flange around the valve has gotten caught under the tire bead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let out the air. Then unscrew the valve stem nut almost up to the top of the valve. You can leave it off as they have no other function as to keep the valve from 'disappearing' into the tyre while installing a tyre. It won't happen anyway with such a long valve!

Then pinch the tyre between thumb and index at the bead from both sides while pushing the valve into the tyre with your other hand. The bead should drop down into the rim. Without (!) tightening the nut on the valve-stem, attach your pump and refill your tyre to low pressure. Take off the chuck of the pump, bounce the wheel several times and check if the bead is properly seated. If not, repeat the operation. Pump to required pressure if it is OK.

Comment: This worked absolutely spot-on. Thanks - was a really good tip to avoid taking the tire off the rim again fully.